# Display query from search bar in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a search bar for users to enter a query. Upon clicking 'Search', a modal should appear with the query results.

My output from index.php is still not showing in the modal. When I click 'Search', the modal pops up with an empty body. **How do I get my output from index.php to show in the modal's body?**

Is there something wrong with my script? Do I need to add something to modal-body?

**index.php**

```html
<head>
  <title>Search</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter query"/>
   <input type="button" name="search" value="Search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">
   </form>
 </body>

<script>
  $('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault() // do not submit form
      // do get request
     $.get( 'search.php', { q : },function(e){
         // then show the modal first
         $('#mymodal').modal('show');
         // then put the results there
         $('#mymodal:visible .modal-content .modal-body').html(e);
     });
  });
</script>

 <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**search.php**

```html
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);

  include_once('db.php'); //Connect to database
  if(isset($_POST['q'])){
    $q = $_POST['q'];

    //get required columns
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%$q%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%$q%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //check for query error
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
      $output = '<h2>No result found</h2>';
    }else{
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['yupikWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['englishWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['audio'].'</h2><br>';
        $audio_name = $row['audio'];
        $output .= '<td><audio src="audio/'.$audio_name.'" controls="control">'.$audio_name.'</audio></td>';
      }
    }
    echo $output;
  }else{
    "Please add search parameter";
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <title>Search</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter query"/>
   <input type="button" name="search" value="Search">
   </form>
   <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" id="showModal" style="display:none;"></button>

 <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>

<script>
  $("body").on("click",'[name="search"]',function(e){
  e.preventDefault() 
     $.post( 'search.php', { q : $('input[name="q"]').val()},function(e){
         // then show the modal first
         $('#mymodal:visible .modal-body').html(e);
         $('#showModal').trigger('click');
         // then put the results there
     });
  });
</script>










<!--search.php-->


<?php
      error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors',1);

      include_once('db.php'); 
      if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])){ // you are using get method in ajax call but in this page you were using $_POST['q'] which is invalid
        $q = $_REQUEST['q'];     // you should either use $_GET['q'] or you could use $_REQUEST['q']. $_REQUEST will work on both $.get method and $.post method of jquery ajax call function 

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%".$q."%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%".$q".%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // you should not use variable in the double quote or single quote. but using in between the quotes will not return any error or warning. but as per my opinion you should not use in between 
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0){
          $output = '<h2>No result found</h2>';
        }else{
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $output .= '<h2>'.$row['yupikWord'].'</h2><br>';
            $output .= '<h2>'.$row['englishWord'].'</h2><br>';
            $output .= '<h2>'.$row['audio'].'</h2><br>';
            $audio_name = $row['audio'];
            $output .= '<td><audio src="audio/'.$audio_name.'" controls="control">'.$audio_name.'</audio></td>';
          }
        }
        echo $output;
      }else{
        "Please add search parameter";
      }

      mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: What'd you change? Answers should have explanations, not just a code dump.

Comment: **if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])){            // earliar it was if(isset($_POST['q'])){

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%".$q."%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%".$q".%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));  //here is a minor change. see this ------------  '%".$q".%'

Comment: The question is not mine. You should write your explanation in the answer. (also maybe add note about SQL injection)

Comment: now please check the code, i have done some comments in the code and tell me did this work for you or not?

Comment: I made the changes but when I click 'Search' the modal is still empty.

Comment: i forgot to put the html changes. now i mentioned the html and php code too. now could you please check it again.

Comment: Still not working. When I try debugging in Chrome there is an error: "Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function"

Comment: i have changed the code from $.get to $.post. now please try. if it is still not working then try the latest jquery library. which is given in below comment:-

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code..
I have modified your code. Added CDN to use bootstrap modal and jquery..and added ajax call to backend. I have also commented out your database variables and replaced with dummy variables..

search.html

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>Search</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="q" id="name" placeholder="Enter query"/>
   <input type="button" name="search" id="submit" value="Search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">
   </form>



 <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">  

        // Ajax post  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#submit").click(function(){  
        var name = $("#name").val();  
         // Returns error message when submitted without req fields.  
        if(name=='')  
        {  
        alert("error");  
        }  
        else  
        {  
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.  
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url:  "http://localhost:8079/test/search.php",  
        data: {name: name},  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(result){  
            if(result!=0){
                console.log(result);
                // On success redirect.  
            $('#mymodal').modal('show');
            $('#mymodal:visible .modal-content .modal-body').html(result);  
            }  
            else { 
               //error
                alert("error");
               }
        }  
        });  
        }  
        return false;  
        });  
        });  
 </script> 

  </html>
```

search.php

```
    <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
    $output="";
 // include_once('db.php'); //Connect to database
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
   // $q = $_POST['q'];

    //get required columns
    /*$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%$q%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%$q%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //check for query error*/
    $count = 2;
    if($count == 0){
      $output = '<h2>No result found</h2>';
    }else{

        $output .= '<h2>Test</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>Test2</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>Test3</h2><br>';
        //$audio_name = $row['audio'];
      //  $output .= '<td><audio src="audio/'.$audio_name.'" controls="control">'.$audio_name.'</audio></td>';

    }
    echo $output;
  }else{
     echo "Error";
  }

 // mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```